# What happens when a Twilight Cleric uses Steps of Night to fly into a brightly lit area?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, duration

The Twilight Domain Cleric's sixth level ability "Steps of Night" reads as follows:

> You can draw on the mystical power of night to rise into the air. As a bonus action when you are in dim light or darkness, you can magically give yourself a flying speed equal to your walking speed for 1 minute.

From the description, it's clear that the Cleric must be out of bright light to use the ability, however it's not clear to me if they can continue to use the ability outside of dim light or darkness.

For example:

- What happens if the Cleric flies into an area that is dimly lit?
- What happens if the Cleric becomes brightly lit by an effect such as the Sunlight spell?

If they are in a region which is brightly lit, can they continue flying or do they fall to ground?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Being in a dimly lit area is only a prerequisite for using the bonus action.

Steps of Night states:

> As a bonus action when you are in dim light or darkness

This indicates that you must be in dim light or darkness to use the bonus action. If you do so, then you:

> give yourself a flying speed equal to your walking speed for 1 minute.

The only end condition given for the flying speed is a one minute expiration. So if you take this bonus action, then you have the flying speed for one minute; no other conditions are put on it (besides the usual rules for flying speeds). You do not have to remain in dim light or darkness to use the flying speed, you just have to be there to use the bonus action.