# Can a Twilight Domain cleric wearing heavy armor still fly using the Steps of Night feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, armor, flight

A player in my campaign is a [Twilight Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#TwilightDomain). The [Steps of Night](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#StepsofNight-2996562) feature (TCoE, p. 35) allows them to gain a flying speed equal to their walking speed for one minute. As a cleric, they have heavy armor proficiency, and they just got some plate armor.

Would they still be able to fly while wearing their plate armour, as it is magical flight rather than with wings? I'm considering whether or not to let them fly.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and maybe visit the [help] in case you need some guidance on posting questions and answers here. Happy gaming!

Comment: Armor interferes with **winged** flight--but most magically-conferred flight is not winged.

Comment: Note that heavy armor proficiency isn't baseline for the cleric class; it's a feature of several subclasses including Twilight.  So giving Twilight clerics heavy armor was definitely an intentional choice.

Answer (score 22):

### Yes, they can use it with heavy armour

There are no general rules for interactions between flying speed and armour, the features that grant flight do what they say.

The *Steps of the Night* feature states:

> (…) As a bonus action when you are in dim light or darkness, you can magically give yourself a flying speed equal to your walking speed for 1 minute. (…)

It includes no restrictions regarding armour, therefore there aren't any. They are allowed to use this with any armour, if there were any restrictions on it, then they would have been explicitly stated, compare to Aarakocra's racial Flight:

> You have a flying speed of 50 feet. To use this speed, you can’t be wearing medium or heavy armor.

As a DM you can obviously overrule any part of the rules but I would advise against doing it mid-game, this is not a corner case or something left up to DM's discretion, changing this would go strictly against RAW. If you do decide to restrict it then I would at the very least allow the player to re-spec their character.

Answer (score 13):

#### Nothing in the rules prevents the Twilight Cleric from flying in heavy armor.

Steps of Night reads:

> You can draw on the mystical power of night to rise into the air. As a bonus action when you are in dim light or darkness, you can magically give yourself a flying speed equal to your walking speed for 1 minute. You can use this bonus action a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

There is nothing here that prevents the flight while wearing heavy armor, nor are there rules specific to heavy or plate armor preventing it either.

When a feature does not permit flight in heavy armor, it says that. For example, the Aarakocra’s flight feature:

> Because of your wings, you have a flying speed equal to your walking speed. *You can’t use **this** flying speed if you’re wearing medium or heavy armor.*

The feature is careful to specify that the limitation applies to “**this** flying speed”. There is no general rule about this, only feature specific rules.

One thing to note, you only have to be in dim light or darkness to *activate* the feature, but you do not have to remain in dim light or darkness to continue flying, see my answer here for details: [What happens when a Twilight Cleric uses Steps of Night to fly into a brightly lit area?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/191933/what-happens-when-a-twilight-cleric-uses-steps-of-night-to-fly-into-a-brightly-l)

Comment: For examples of classes where most features don't work while wearing (heavy) armor, see Barbarian and Monk.  Most of their class features do explicitly say "while you aren't wearing heavy armor" (barbarian) or "While you aren't wearing armor or using a shield" (Monk).  Rage benefits are disabled but you could still Reckless Attack, for example.  Anyway, point being that they do repeat the phrasing about armor over several different features when that's what they mean. (Also, being proficient or not is irrelevant for most class features, except spellcasting. A plated barbarian can flail around)

Answer (score 6):

#### The feature allows to fly regardless the armor type.

The complete text of the feature says:

> You can draw on the mystical power of night to rise into the air. As a bonus action when you are in dim light or darkness, you can magically give yourself a flying speed equal to your walking speed for 1 minute. You can use this bonus action a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

It is clear that there is no restriction about heavy armor. For reference, have a look at the Flight trait of Aarakocra:

> Because of your wings, you have a fly­ing speed equal to your walking speed. **You can’t use this flying speed if you’re wearing medium or heavy armor.**

In this case, the limitation are explicitly stated.

---

As a DM, you may obviously overrule some features, game characteristics, spells, et cetera that you may feel will disrupt the game or cause some problems.

At the table, when some new features that I think that might cause some issues come into the game (and I think this is not one of them), as a DM I usually says "*Ok, let's apply the rules in this way and let's see how they will turn out. In case they are overpowered/underpowerd or if some problems arise, we'll modify them*".